# How supplement the Laravel 5.5 react preset with redux

Tags: laravel, reactjs, react-redux

As title says, how can I add redux to my react frontend when using Laravel/Laravel mix as of 5.5?

---

So far I have attempted the following.

```
npm install --save redux
npm install --save react-redux
```

Then, upon running `npm run dev` I get the following error which I can not encode to anything useful ...

```
> @ dev /home/anders/Code/project
> npm run development
> @ development /home/anders/Code/project
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:192:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:374:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/anders/.npm/_logs/2017-12-21T13_57_49_940Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: "npm run development"
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/anders/.npm/_logs/2017-12-21T13_57_50_015Z-debug.log
```

I did get a boilerplate non-laravel-mix react/redux  app up and running by cloning this repo: https://github.com/buckyroberts/React-Redux-Boilerplate. Looking at that projects package.json I tried to mimic it but could not build as seen above.

Im running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually adding it with versions to my composer.json:

```
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2"
```

At the time of this posting it is problably outdated but it got me running.

I copied a pure react/redux app into Laravel for some boilerplate. Dumping it here if anyone is interested: https://github.com/ajthinking/laravel-react-redux/tree/master